# Customizing MFA page on Portal

Tags: mfa

I am trying to figure out how to customize the RemoteAccessAuthorizationPage to allow our users to sign up for any MFA rather than force them to SF Authenticator as a default.

But I can't find that page.  Where/How do I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: It works like that out of the box - you can choose a 3rd party TOTP rather than SF authenticator. See https://www.salesforce.com/content/dam/web/en_us/www/documents/white-papers/2fa-admin-rollout-guide.pdf

Comment: But I want to modify it so it isn't so SF! I want it to look like our other pages.  Is there no way to modify it?

Comment: Unfortunately - no. You have to build your own page from scratch and insert it into your login workflow, in whole a risky proposition.